# Speech recognition results comparing to chinese unicode

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to develop a app for my country's elderly. In a multi-racial country, i need to detect voice for English and Chinese(for now). I am having some problems with comparing the output, which is in chinese, to a Chinese unicode or character.

for example if the voice recognised 救命(help), which would be a right way to compare?

Currently I am using this.

`if(d[i] .equals("help") || d[i] .equals("&#25937;&#21629;"))`

sadly it doesn't work. Any help here guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encoded your Chinese characters using HTML encoding, which is inappropriate for Java source code. Try:

```
if(d[i] .equals("help") || d[i] .equals("\u6551\u547d"))
```

See [section 3.3 Unicode Escapes of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) for complete information.